# Receive wrong representation of non-unicode characters in request to controller ("ÐÐ¾" instead of "Сыр")

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/item/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ProductDto[] getProducts(Pageable pageable, @RequestParam(value = "searchDto", required = false) String serializedDto) throws IOException {
```

I send this request:

```
...item/products?page=0&size=10&sort=status,asc&sort=id,asc&searchDto={"name":"Сыр"}
```

"Сыр" - Cyrillic

And in controller I receive this:

```
serializedDto = {"name":"ÐÐ¾"}
```

instead of this:

```
serializedDto = {"name":"Сыр"}
```

Problem is in encoding, I have tried a lot of things but they didn't work.
What I'm doing wrong? If you need more code/materials I will provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using tomcat then consider that by default it is ignoring url parameters encoding. For maven plugin add the next configuration:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <uriEncoding>utf-8</uriEncoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

or configure your [tomcat http connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

Answer (score 0):

Register an instance of `CharacterEncodingFilter` as a `ServletFilter`. In a typical spring mvc java config you would have an extension of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` class like following:

```
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter};
      }
```

Traditional spring mvc apps would've a `web.xml` like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In boot web app, just add a filter bean to your web configuration, something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {  
      @Bean
      public Filter CharacterEncodingFilter() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return CharacterEncodingFilter;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I already had that code in `web.xml`, and just added @Bean configuration, and still problem remains.